# MongoDB Atlas. Cant create roles with built-in-role "atlasAdmin"

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I'm using the built-in-role "Atlas admin".

When running the command:

```
db.runCommand({
  "createRole": "555-read",
  "roles": [],
  "privileges": [
    {
      "actions": [
        "find"
      ],
      "resource": {
        "db": "qqq",
        "collection": "555"
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

I get:

```
MongoServerError: not authorized on qqq to execute command { createRole: "555-read"
```

I think the "Atlas admin" should have access to everything?

Or do I need to some specific privliages in atlas?

Comment: I assume, you can create roles only via the Atlas Web interface.

Comment: Or via API https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/reference/api-resources-spec/#tag/Custom-Database-Roles/operation/listCustomDatabaseRoles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, you cannot create create roles in mongo shell. You can check privileges with this:

```
db.runCommand({ connectionStatus: 1 })
{
  authInfo: {
    authenticatedUsers: [ { user: 'atlas-admin', db: 'admin' } ],
    authenticatedUserRoles: [
      { role: 'atlasAdmin', db: 'admin' },
      { role: 'backup', db: 'admin' },
      { role: 'clusterMonitor', db: 'admin' },
      { role: 'dbAdminAnyDatabase', db: 'admin' },
      { role: 'enableSharding', db: 'admin' },
      { role: 'readWriteAnyDatabase', db: 'admin' }
    ]
  },
  ok: 1,
  operationTime: Timestamp({ t: 1679383010, i: 1 })
}

db.runCommand({ connectionStatus: 1, showPrivileges: 1 }).authInfo.authenticatedUserPrivileges.filter(x => x.resource.collection == 'system.roles')
[
  {
    resource: { db: 'admin', collection: 'system.roles' },
    actions: [ 'find' ]
  }
]
```

As you see, you can only select roles. Privilege `userAdmin` or `userAdminAnyDatabase` is not granted.